# Get Latitude and Longitude in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, ruby-on-rails-6

In JavaScript, I can easily get my current Latitude and Longitude Coordinates and I'm trying to implement this in Ruby On Rails

In Javascript, I can use the following code to get my current Latitude and Longitude.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

In Rails, I am able to get my current IP address using the following

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://checkip.amazonaws.com/')).squish
```

However, I am unable to convert this to a latitude and longitude,

The Javascript approach asks the users permission to use their current location which would be ideal for the scenario I am facing. I realise that there are gems out there that tackle this problem however I need this to work on localhost which the javascript method does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geocoder` gem will not work with localhost. And if to use it in production it can only give **approximate** results.

More precise result can be received by sending ajax request from frontend to backend.

Example:
[image]

```
<!-- application.html.erb -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noty/3.1.0/noty.js' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noty/3.1.0/noty.min.css' %>

    <script>
      // It's bad to write inline javascript. To be moved into separate .js file
      $(function() {
        Noty.overrideDefaults({ theme: 'relax', layout: 'topCenter' });

        $('.getLocation').click(function(e) {
          event.preventDefault();

          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              $('.latInput').val(position.coords.latitude);
              $('.longInput').val(position.coords.longitude);

              new Noty({
                text: "Got location",
                type: "success"
              }).show();
            }, function(position) {
              new Noty({
                text: "Could not get location",
                type: "error"
              }).show();
            });
          } else {
            new Noty({
              text: "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.",
              type: "error"
            }).show();
          }
        });

        $('.resetLocation').click(function(e) {
          event.preventDefault();

          $('.latInput').val('');
          $('.longInput').val('');
        });

        $('.submitAjax').click(function(e) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var lat = $('.latInput').val();
          var long = $('.longInput').val();
          if (lat && long) {
            $.ajax({
              url: "/",
              data: {
                lat: lat,
                long: long
              }
            }).done(function() {
              new Noty({
                text: "Data was successfully submitted to server via AJAX",
                type: "success"
              }).show();
            }).fail(function() {
              new Noty({
                text: "Couldn't send data",
                type: "error"
              }).show();
            });
          } else {
            new Noty({
              text: "Click on 'Get Location' button first",
              type: "error"
            }).show();
          }
        });

        $('.clearAndSubmit').click(function(e) {
          $('.latInput').val('');
          $('.longInput').val('');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%
      ip = request.remote_ip
      ip = '8.8.8.8' if ip.in?(["::1", "127.0.0.1"])
    %>
    Geocoder.search(ip):
    <br />
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10"><%= Geocoder.search(ip) %></textarea>
    <hr />
    <% if params[:lat].present? && params[:long].present? %>
      Form was submitted:
      <br />
      Lat: <%= params[:lat] %>
      <br />
      Long: <%= params[:lat] %>
    <% else %>
      Form was not submitted
    <% end %>
    <br />
    <br />
    <%= form_tag '/', method: :get do |f| %>
      <button class="getLocation">Get Location</button>
      &nbsp;
      <button class="resetLocation">Reset Location</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <%= label_tag :lat, 'Lat:' %>
      <%= text_field_tag :lat, params[:lat], class: 'latInput' %>      
      <%= label_tag :long, 'Long:' %>
      <%= text_field_tag :long, params[:long], class: 'longInput' %>      
      <br />
      <br />
      <button class="submitAjax">Submit location to server via ajax</button>      
      <br />
      <br />
      <%= submit_tag "Submit location to server via form submit" %>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button class="clearAndSubmit">Clear form and submit</button>      
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

```rb
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action do
    # Implemented before_action for demonstration purposes. Should be moved into action.

    if params[:lat].present? && params[:long].present?
      Rails.logger.info(['Received lat&long from AJAX request', {lat: params[:lat], long: params[:long]}])
      # current_user.lat = params[:lat]
      # current_user.lat = params[:lng]
      # current_user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# gemfile.rb
#...
gem 'geocoder'
```

Comment: As per my question, I require this to work on localhost

Comment: If you will send AJAX request from JavaScript to Rails, it will work on localhost. In code snippet that I provided you can see an example of AJAX request. Just ignore the code related to `geocoder` gem

Answer (score 1):

you can use geocoder gem

first open your Gemfiles and add this line

```
gem 'geocoder'
```

from terminal run bundle install to install gem files
then run rails console to test it here is sample to search for latitude and longitude for 10 downing street, london

```
results = Geocoder.search("10 Downing Street, london")
latitude = results.first.coordinates[0]
longitude = results.first.coordinates[1]
```